# Peer dependency errors when installing npm packages

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, rxjs

Does anyone know a solution to the following errors.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: x
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from react-native-webview@11.26.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-webview
npm ERR!     react-native-webview@"^11.6.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native@0.71.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from react-native-webview@11.26.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-webview
npm ERR!     react-native-webview@"^11.6.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
```

Cannot figure out why it won't work. Deleted node modules + package.json (lock)

ran npm i + npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 2):

The error message you gave shows that NPM couldn't fix a problem with your project's dependencies. In particular, there seems to be a problem between two dependencies that need different versions of React.

The first dependency, `react-native-webview`, requires peer `react@*`, which means it can work with any version of ReactJS. The second dependency, `react-native`, requires peer `react@18.2.0`, which means it specifically requires version `18.2.0` of React.

Since you have `react@17.0.2` installed, your peer-dependencies are incompatible.

---

When approaching problems like this, you want to think of the most restrictive dependency. Since `react-native-webview` works with any version of React, we don't have to worry about this. Since `react-native` requires `v18.2` of ReactJS, you will have to conform your project to this dependency.

In your `package.json` file, you will need to update:

```json
...
"dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2"
}
...
```

with `"react": "18.2.0"`

Comment: After completing the above getting some more errors which I believe are conflicting? -->

`npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.14.0" from react-dom@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   react-dom@"^16.8.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">=16.8.6" from @ionic/react@5.9.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic/react
npm ERR!     @ionic/react@"^5.5.0" from the root project
`

Comment: You need to update `react-dom` to the same version as React

Comment: Like @ChrisSandvik mentioned, all your libraries must be updated so that they are all compatible with the same version of React/ReactNative. If you provide your entire `package.json` file, then I go through all the dependencies and give you the correct versions.